# Can we read about the privacy policy changes somewhere besides meta.se?

Tags: discussion, support

Today there's a banner up top that says

> We changed our privacy policy. Read more.

The link goes to meta.stackexchange.com.

For...reasons, I don't read meta.stackexchange.com.  I even have it blocked on my PC.

Is there another location where we can read about these privacy changes?  Can the post be duplicated here somewhere, for instance?

Comment: It's not great but you can view the [diff view](https://gist.github.com/pxeger/f00bae9440f0c8bc5d88c389c84b9e47/revisions#diff-4e8eff6c864aa6ec56c1f7ae983cb7889a3349e48e60d19bf0bf5cb0fe5213bf)

Comment: A bit off-topic but: how do you block it?

Comment: @Clockwork I set `meta.stackexchange.com` to resolve to `127.0.0.1` in my [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)).

Comment: A 3rd-party service like [Stack Printer](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite) might be helpful: http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=370216&service=meta.stackexchange

Comment: Seems like it's printing the entire page though, so it's not so far from "reading meta.stackexchange.com" as asker put it (since you have the post, the answers and all the comments).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the post by Phillipe:

> As you know, periodically we update our privacy policy. Today is one of those days: we've made a few changes to the privacy policy. The policy covers how we collect and use data on the entire network, including Stack Overflow for Teams and the public Q&A site.
>
> Changes include:
>
> - The privacy notice was completely redrafted and updated to ensure it remains accurate, up to date, and effective.
> - The International Data transfer section was updated to reflect that we no longer rely on the Privacy Shield to transfer data across borders.
> - The structure of the sections and layout of the privacy notice was simplified to make it clearer and easier to navigate.
> - We previously had three separate notices for Teams; one each for Free, Basic, and Business - these were merged into a single privacy notice covering Free, Basic, and Business together.
> - Enterprise Privacy Notice was updated.
> - A new policy was created for Collectives on Stack Overflow.
> - The policy now covers employer branding, which is an ad product.
> - The policy has been updated to reflect changes to privacy laws and the privacy landscape.
>
> The [Privacy Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy) can be found in the footer of every page on the network, and - for visibility - we are using the site banner to direct users to this question.

---

There is *a lot* not covered in his post that is being hashed out by various other community members, but this is all I can copy here due to the length of each answer.